# Connection to Postgres (AWS RDS) with Google Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, postgresql, firebase, google-cloud-functions, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect to my AWS rds postgres database through my Google Firebase Functions backend. After some trial and error, I successfully managed to connect to it locally (ran `firebase emulators:start --only functions` and successfully queried the DB). However, I am running into a `{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306` when I deploy my function to the remote Google Firebase Functions server.

I have set my AWS RDS database to publicly accessible. I know that I need to allow inbound traffic from my Google Firebase server, but from what I managed to dig up, [this](http://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json) shows that the Availability Zone I am using (us-central-1) has dozens of IP addresses associated with it. I gave up and allowed all incoming traffic (Yes I know that's bad but I am not in production just yet). However, I am still getting the same error!

I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361088/aws-rds-postgres-connection-failure) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959948/change-security-group-on-aws-rds-database-instance) to no avail.

Any ideas on how to get this working, and how to connect it properly so I'm not allowing all incoming traffic?

Below is how I am connecting to my aws db in my firebase function. The function itself (where the code is stored) is us-central:

```
  const {Pool} = require('pg');

  private static readonly config = {
    user: 'xxxxxxxx',
    host: 'xxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
    database: 'postgres',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    port: 5432
  };
  private static readonly pool = new Pool(RemoteDBHandler.config);
```

Edit: Looking at it now, it is odd that the connection is being attempted on localhost (127.0.0.1). I have no idea why that's happening, since I am making the connection to the aws server. Therefore, I don't think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955122/firebase-cloud-functions-econnrefused) applies to me